# How to loop over nested arrays in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Consider the following object:

```
[{
  key: 'value',
  amounts: [{key: 'value}]
}]
```

This array is tied to a observableArray, we will call this foo.

```
self.foo = ko.observableArray([{
  key: 'value',
  amounts: [{key: 'value}]
}])
```

Then we can do:

```
  <div id="something" data-bind="foreach: foo">
    <div class="somethingElse">
        // How do I get the amounts here?
    </div>
  </div>
```

So how would I, inside the element, get "amounts"? would it be:

```
data-bind="foreach: foo.amounts"
```

Seems logical to me ...

Comment: `data-bind="foreach: amounts"`

Comment: So you dont want internet points? How am I suppose to accept this? Also more explanation as to how it knows about nested arrays please.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `foreach` binding, the inner HTML is repeated and each section is bound to an item from the array. It is bound as a "child" context" and so can directly access the properties of the array item.

Since the object bound to the inner HTML is

```
{
  key: 'value',
  amounts: [{key: 'value}]
}
```

You can use the properties directly

```
data-bind="foreach: amounts"
```